# How do you pronounce $\mathcal{L}$

Tags: notation, random-variables, finance

How do you pronounce $\mathcal{L}$?

It almost always denotes a random variable of losses in a portfolio.  It comes up a lot in my "Essential mathematics for market risk management" book, and I feel a bit silly calling it "curly L" to the portfolio managers I work with.

Comment: I just call it the letter "L". It's just a fancy way of writing that letter.

Comment: You could say Script L

Comment: Or just "random variable of losses" :)

Comment: All good answers.  Thank you!

Comment: Unless you have a formula where you're both using $L$ and $\mathcal L$, what's the problem with just referring to it as "ell", as The Count says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use either 'luh' or 'ell'.